# Creating iOS shortcut game with levels

Tags: ios, xml

How can I make levels in iOS shortcuts?

i'm making a game which will be about changing some settings to finish levels (logic game) i had idea to make autosave because levels will require that. my idea was about using rarely used system app named 'reminders' where i can save progress in a part of one reminder named 'notes' but shortuts app doesn't recognize 'otherwise' feature for if loop and when i tap shortcut it adds only one more reminder and doesn't show upcoming first level ios version is 14.4.1 (beta i think) and tablet is after JB (but i've never modified shortcuts app) .

xml source from shortcut (github) : https://github.com/hacknorris-notyetbanned/hacknorris.github.io/blob/77a47bff65bc13f21642dbebdf4023aa957ebb0a/Test.xml

where is bug in reminders?

Edit: now i wont mess up on shortcuts - im gonna update this : https://github.com/hacknorris-notyetbanned/glitched.git and leave project. I have 0 ideas and logged out of icloud...  :/

Comment: It's still very unclear to me what you're trying to do or what problem you're having. Walk us through it step by step. Assume we've never seen a game anything like your game before.

Comment: is now okay ? or yet bad?

Comment: "changing some settings to finish levels" - which settings? Also, I don't understand the part about using the shortuts app - from what I could tell by searching, that's not a development tool (something that you would use to make software) but a productivity app (something that makes the device more useful).

Comment: so why someone made that : https://shortcuts.fun/ ? It's also for free ios development if you don't know. and secondly - things i wanted inside - changing volume/brightness to pass levels, also in share sheet to finish some levels which'd just detect some types of media (like photo/audio), switching networks, bluetooth... - something like that : https://apps.apple.com/us/app/blackbox-think-outside-the-box/id962969578 or that : https://apps.apple.com/us/app/enigmbox-test-your-brain/id648390373 i wanted to make ;)

Comment: oh and next framework for shortcut apps : https://github.com/adamtow/shortcut-app-framework/blob/master/documentation.md how not app if app?